# API route to a Many-To-Many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api

I have a related REST API question.

I have 2 entities, `Product` and `Store`, which has a `many-to-many` relationship between them. A `Product` may be available in 0 or more `Store`s and a `Store` may have 0 or more `Product`s.

But I need a route to add a `Product` to a `Store` and also a route to remove a `Product` from a `Store`. The relationship is simple, there is no extra column in the pivot table.

Which approach would you use?

Comment: Please accept my answer if you found it useful and answered your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Products cannot exist without a Store and must belong to a Store, then it makes sense to nest the route under Stores.

For example:

Add a new Product to a Store

```
POST /api/store/:id/product/:id
```

Delete a Product from a Store

```
DELETE /api/store/:id/product/:id
```

Either way, it still seems more logical to nest the API routes for adding/deleting products to/from stores, under Store. With this design, the Store is the main focus and you are adding or deleting products from it. It is simple and easy to understand and follow.

Whereas in the alternative design, the Product is the main focus and you are adding stores in which it is being sold in or deleting stores in which it is no longer being sold in. It becomes more complicated than necessary.

Comment: I'm sorry, my fault. A product can exists without a store. It'll not be displayed.

Comment: Either way, it still seems more logical to nest the API routes for adding/deleting products to/from stores, under Store.

With this design, the Store is the main focus and you are adding or deleting products from it. It is simple and easy to understand and follow.

Whereas in the alternative design, the Product is the main focus and you are adding stores in which it is being sold in or deleting stores in which it is no longer being sold in. It becomes more complicated.

Comment: I thought something like `PUT /api/store/{id}/product/{id}` to add a link a product to a store - and `DELETE /api/store/{id}/product/{id}` to unlink. so I can have `Store\ProductController@update` and `Store\ProductController@destroy`

Comment: I edited my previous comment to give a more thorough explanation. Yes, that sounds correct, but do you mean POST to create or add a new product to a store instead of PUT?

Comment: Yah, POST instead of PUT.

Comment: But I think I need to set the store id on the route. Please edit your answer so that I can set as correct.

Comment: Done @IanRodrigues :)

Answer (score 0):

You simply should define in your product store method, that your saved product belongs to chosed stores.

Take a look in Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: Yep. I know how this works, but I'm not talking about this. I want a route to add a product to a store, for instance `PUT api/product/{id}/store/{id}` without payload, that can be one option.

Answer (score 0):

If you work for the Product company, and you're keeping track of which stores carry which products, then you would POST to /api/product/{id} to add the store.

If you work for the Store company, which *decides* which products to carry in which stores, then you would POST to /api/store/{id} to add a product.

Note that I suggest POST, because neither operation is actually creating a product or store.

Comment: And if a store has many customers and a customers could visit many stores? What the /api/store/{id} "POST" method should catch? Adding a products or a Customer? Doesn't seem to be clear with that route